# Is it good practice to use revert() in case a function does find a match in case of a search?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, revert-opcode

This Solidity function:

```
function findSupplierByName(string supplierName) public view returns (address id, string name) {
    for (uint idx = 0; idx < supplierAddresses.length; idx++) {
        address supplierAddress = supplierAddresses[idx];
        var supplier = suppliers[supplierAddress];

        if (keccak256(supplier.name) == keccak256(supplierName)) {
            return (
                supplier.id,
                supplier.name
            );
        }
    }

    revert();
}
```

Is this correct ?
Or should I just remove the **revert();** statement, so that this function returns a 0 for address and a "" for the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to revert() if the function does NOT find the data.
To maintain consistency with what the function does, i'd have it return `(address(0), "")` and have the calling function choose what to do when it gets a null address value.

If the function is ALWAYS supposed to find a result, you might want to change `revert()` to `assert(supplier.id != address(0))`.

Comment: Is adding a boolean which indicates found or not found also a good option?

function findSupplierByName(string supplierName) public view returns (bool found, address id, string name) 

?